# Unable to upgrade hashicorp/aws version from 3.0 to 5.0 in terraform versions.tf

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

I tried to upgrade my hashicorp/aws provider version from 3.0 to 5.0 in terraform version.tf i got the below error when terraform init is executed

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: locked provider
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 3.76.1 does not match configured version constraint ~> 3.0, ~> 5.0; must
│ use terraform init -upgrade to allow selection of new versions
```

This is how my versions.tf file looks

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

currently i am using terraform 1.5.5 version. Please let me know how to upgrade my hashicorp/aws provider version

Comment: Remove the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file and run `terraform init`.

Comment: i tried removing the .terraform.lock.hcl file still the error is coming

Comment: The only reason for that to happen is if you have a module somewhere and it is using the provider version specified in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to currently have two problems but the error message of one is hiding the error message of the other.

The first problem is that you seem to be running `terraform init` instead of `terraform init -upgrade`, and so Terraform is trying to preserve the provider dependency selections from the dependency lock file. If your goal is to upgrade to a newer version of the provider then you must run `terraform init -upgrade` to give Terraform permission to ignore the selections previously recorded in the lock file.

If you do that then I expect you will find the second error: your configuration contains conflicting version requirements for this provider. There is no version that can match both `~> 3.0` and `~> 5.0` at the same time, because the first only allows `3.x` releases while the second only allows `5.x` releases. You can run `terraform providers` to see a summary of which modules in your configuration contain which provider requirements. You'll need to change your modules so that together they can agree on a single version of the provider to use.

Typically a `required_providers` block should use only `>=` constraints unless you already know that your module is incompatible with newer provider versions, since the dependency lock file already ensures that you won't accidentally install a newer version after making your initial selections. However, the AWS provider does have some breaking changes between the `3.x` series and the `5.x` series, so it's possible that some of your modules might be incompatible with `5.x` releases and so you'll need to update those modules to work with the newer release.

Comment: Even i tried with the command terraform init -upgrade got below error

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.0, ~> 5.0"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: no available releases match
│ the given constraints ~> 3.0, ~> 5.0

Comment: Did you try deleting your .terraform.lock.hcl and running terraform init as suggested by Marko ?

Comment: The error message you described in your reply is exactly the second error message I addressed in the second part of my answer.

Comment: (Deleting the dependency lock file is essentially equivalent to running `terraform init -upgrade`, so it is a different way to solve the first problem but it will not help with the second problem.)